# Learning Resources for mongodb and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

More I'm going on with MongoID driver for MongoDB nosql models in my Rails apps, more I feel don't knowing so much about the full expressiveness, elasticity and powerness of its constructs.

Mongoid [docs](http://mongoid.org/) is one of the clearest, easy and usefull documentation around the blok, but still not enough to understand the implication in the deep.

Think for example at the design/performance/scalability/refactorability implication of using [embedded one to many](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-n.html) vs [referenced one to many](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-n.html)

I'm looking for source of examples and eventually online tutorials, articles and books to go deeper here.

Thanks in advance
luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design and scalability are more related to the database itself. I'm going through "MongoDb the definitive guide" book right now before jumping into mongoid to gain better understanding